# Compiling 32 bit Assembler on 64 bit ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, assembly, 64-bit, 32-bit

I have program written in 32 bit assembly language... Now I just can't compile it on 64 bit OS. On our school they are specific and program has to be written in 32 bit version. Here is my program:

```
bits 32
extern _printf
global _start

section .data
    message db "Hello world!!", 10, 0

section .text

_start:
    pushad 
    push dword message
    call _printf 
    add esp, 4 
    popad 
    ret
```

Any idea? I have tried so many ways to compile that.
Error output after compiling:

```
nasm -f elf64 vaja4.asm
ld vaja4.o -o vaja4
./vaja4
```

output:

```
vaja4.o: In function `_start':
vaja4.asm:(.text+0x7): undefined reference to `_printf'
```

Comment: shouldn't that be printf not _printf ?

Comment: Same error: vaja4.o: In function `start':
vaja4.asm:(.text+0x7): undefined reference to `printf'

Answer (score 25, accepted):

First change `_printf` to `printf` and the `_start` symbol to `main`, then use `gcc` to link the object file, which will automatically link it to `libc`, *you need to do that because AFAIK you can't link to libc without a `main`*. Also you should use elf32 not elf64 when assembling because the code has 32 bits instructions :

```
bits 32
extern printf
global main

section .data
    message db "Hello world!!", 10, 0

section .text

main:
    pushad 
    push dword message
    call printf 
    add esp, 4 
    popad 
    ret
```

And build with:

```
nasm -f elf32 vaja4.asm
gcc -m32 vaja4.o -o vaja4
$./test 
$Hello world!!
```

**Edit:**

Since you're now compiling 32-bit code on a 64-bit system, you will need to install the 32-bit version of the libraries

```
apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Comment: Yes, this is the right way. If you want to use libc you should use `main` as entry point and link using gcc so that the proper pieces of libc are pulled in and the initialization/shutdown are taken care of. Also, simply returning only works from `main`, if you create a binary without libc you must use an exit system call.

Comment: Well I tried your way. After gcc -m32 vaja4.o -o vaja4 it gives me that error output:

http://pastebin.com/jX3N2GSJ

Comment: you need to install the 32-bits libraries apt-get install ia32-libs

Comment: I tried to install that libraries and still same error. Now I install libc6-dev-i386 libraries and it works! Ty :)

Comment: You can link libc from a program that only defines `_start`.  If you make a static binary, though, you have to call glibc's init functions, or use a libc like musl that doesn't need init functions.  (dynamic linking on Linux calls glibc's init functions before `_start`).  See my answer on the question I marked this one a duplicate of.  (The `_printf` vs. `printf` issue is separate, but otherwise it's asking the same thing)

Answer (score 9):

On Ubuntu 12.10, you need to install development packages first

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libc6-dev-i386
```

for

```
gcc -m32 vaja4.o -o vaja4
```

to work.

Answer (score 4):

I doubt that the error you see is because of 32/64 bit issue. The error that you see i.e

```
vaja4.asm:(.text+0x7): undefined reference to `_printf'
```

is clearly telling you the symbol _printf is undefined which means that the library for printf function is not being linked.

your linking step i.e

```
ld vaja4.o -o vaja4
```

does not include any libraries. You need to link your program with a library that can provide definition of the printf function. I believe ld should pick the library it self without bothering you with these messages but because it is not able to find a suitable C library for this function, I guess you dont have the required libraries i.e either 32 bit or 64 library is missing.

Anyway, plz try the following sequence of commands to assemble and link your program:

```
nasm -f elf vaja4.asm
ld -m elf_i386 vaja4.o vaja4
./vaja4
```

Comment: Or even `ld -m elf_i386 -I/lib/ld-linux.so.2 -lc vaja4.o -o vaja4` Might not need the `-I` switch - definitely need `-lc` and `-o` on the output file name. The `_start ` label is jumped to, not called. so you can't `ret` from it. Easier to use `main` and gcc...

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you forgot to link against the C library, which is the part that provides the `printf` function (and others):

```
ld vaja4.o -o vaja4 -lc
```