# NASM printf Ubuntu 64-bit v12.04

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, gcc, nasm

I'm trying to use printf statement in NASM. I tried to assemble and link [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8194407/3922867) code with command given in comment of the code, but terminal shows following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crt1.o: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc  
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/libgcc_s.so when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/libgcc_s.so when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crtn.o: No such file or directory
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: How do you call the assember? How do you call the linker? Please provide the complete command lines with all flags.

Comment: As given in the link. 
nasm -f elf printf-test.asm && gcc -m32 -o printf-test printf-test.o .
Edited the question now.

Comment: Have you installed the 32-bit libraries?

Comment: Ooops... nope. I'm downloading now. with  `apt-get install ia32-libs` command. Right?

Comment: Still getting the same errors after running command `apt-get install ia32-libs`.

Comment: Not familiar with Ubuntu, but generally you need both gcc-32bit and the runtime libraries libgcc-32bit. (on SuSE) Poke around and see if you find something similar.

Comment: After installing `libc6-dev-i386`, it is working now. I found this solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13178501/compiling-32-bit-assembler-on-64-bit-ubuntu#comment17936499_13179154)