# How to assemble an ASM file into an x86 shellcode on a Linux 64 bits?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, shellcode

I have this following ASM file:

```
; Call to sys_chmod
; eax = 15 (0xf)
; ebx = filepath "/tmp/before"
; ecx = mode: 0777 (0x1ff)
xor eax, eax
mov al, 0xf

xor ebx, ebx
push ebx
push dword 0x65726f66
push dword 0x65622f70
push dword 0x6d742f2f
lea ebx, [esp]

mov cx, 0x1ff

int 0x80

nop
```

Briefly, this ASM code is the equivalent of the command `chmod 777 /tmp/before`. I would like to convert this code into an x86 shellcode which is:

```
\x31\xC0\xB0\x0F\x31\xDB\x53\x68\x66\x6F\x72\x65\x68\x70\x2F\x62\x65\x68\x2F\x2F\x74\x6D\x8D\x1C\x24\x66\xB9\xFF\x01\xCD\x80\x90
```

I used an [online assembler](https://defuse.ca/online-x86-assembler.htm) to do the conversion but I would like to be able to do it on my own with my Linux 64bits.

I looked at different answers but none of them corresponds to what I want. For instance, in [Compiling 32 bit Assembler on 64 bit ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13179154/7334162), it uses nasm to generate an elf32. However this file contains more than just the shellcode I want:

```
$ nasm -f elf32 chmod.asm -o chmod.o
$ xxd chmod.o 
00000000: 7f45 4c46 0101 0100 0000 0000 0000 0000  .ELF............
00000010: 0100 0300 0100 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000020: 4000 0000 0000 0000 3400 0000 0000 2800  @.......4.....(.
00000030: 0500 0200 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000040: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000050: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000060: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0100 0000 0100 0000  ................
00000070: 0600 0000 0000 0000 1001 0000 2000 0000  ............ ...
00000080: 0000 0000 0000 0000 1000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000090: 0700 0000 0300 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000000a0: 3001 0000 2100 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  0...!...........
000000b0: 0100 0000 0000 0000 1100 0000 0200 0000  ................
000000c0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 6001 0000 3000 0000  ........`...0...
000000d0: 0400 0000 0300 0000 0400 0000 1000 0000  ................
000000e0: 1900 0000 0300 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000000f0: 9001 0000 0b00 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000100: 0100 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000110: 31c0 b00f 31db 5368 666f 7265 6870 2f62  1...1.Shforehp/b
00000120: 6568 2f2f 746d 8d1c 2466 b9ff 01cd 8090  eh//tm..$f......
00000130: 002e 7465 7874 002e 7368 7374 7274 6162  ..text..shstrtab
00000140: 002e 7379 6d74 6162 002e 7374 7274 6162  ..symtab..strtab
00000150: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000160: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000170: 0100 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0400 f1ff  ................
00000180: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0300 0100  ................
00000190: 0063 686d 6f64 2e61 736d 0000 0000 0000  .chmod.asm......
```

I could retrieve the shellcode from the generated elf32 file starting at the offset 0x110 but is there an easiest solution to get just the shellcode?

Comment: Use `-f bin` to generate a binary file and `bits 32` to generate 32 bit code.

Comment: Your shellcode is 32 bit code.  It will run on an 64-bit Linux system, if you incorporate it into a 32-bit executable, but if you want 64-bit shellcode you need to start over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As indicated by @fuz in his comment, the ASM file must contains the `[BITS 32]` directive to specify the target processor mode. It gives:

```
; Call to sys_chmod
; eax = 15 (0xf)
; ebx = filepath "/tmp/before"
; ecx = mode: 0777 (0x1ff)
[BITS 32]
xor eax, eax
mov al, 0xf

xor ebx, ebx
push ebx
push dword 0x65726f66
push dword 0x65622f70
push dword 0x6d742f2f
lea ebx, [esp]

mov cx, 0x1ff

int 0x80

nop
```

By default, the `nasm` command generates a binary, it is not necessary to provide the `-f bin` option:

```
nasm chmod.asm
```

Then, `hexdump` can be used to generate the shellcode in the correct format:

```
$ hexdump -v -e '"\\""x" 1/1 "%02x" ""' chmod
\x31\xc0\xb0\x0f\x31\xdb\x53\x68\x66\x6f\x72\x65\x68\x70\x2f\x62\x65\x68\x2f\x2f\x74\x6d\x8d\x1c\x24\x66\xb9\xff\x01\xcd\x80\x90
```